# Does PL/I put a newline BEFORE the current line?

Tags: pl-i

I've been reading about PL/I just for interest (I like learning about old programming languages). I see a lot of output statements of the form

```
PUT SKIP LIST 'Hello, world!'
```

and I understand this outputs a newline character followed by the data ('Hello, world!'). Is this the normal way around for PL/I? What is the rationale for that? In almost all other languages, the convention is to output a newline character at the end of the line:

```
print('Hello, world!\n');
```

How do you do that in PL/I? (Or maybe you just don't?)

Comment: From what I read the idea of the PUT statement is that you specify what to put as well as where to put it, similar to PostScript/PDF. The positioning is conceptually connected to the line that you are going to write, not to the previous line. A nice example can be found in [A Guide to PL/I for Commercial Programmers](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/360/pli/SC20-1651-1_A_Guide_to_PL_I_for_Commercial_Programmers_Apr68.pdf) from 1968, page 32 (33 in the pdf).